# Where to set popover size?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` called `HomeViewController` and it has a model that contains an array of data.  `HomeViewController` also has a button that when pressed will show a `UITableViewController` that display's the model's array of data.

My question is, what is the standard/best way to set the popover's size? I only want the popover to be tall enough to display the data, but no taller.  What is common practice? I assume that I need to set `contentSizeForViewInPopover` at some point but I'm not sure where...In the `viewDidLoad` method of the popover class? In the `prepareForSegue` method?

Here's the code I have so far: (Note that `DataPresentingViewController` is my popover view controller class`)

```
//In HomeViewController
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[DataPresentingViewController class]])
    {
        DataPresentingViewController *dest = (DataPresentingViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        dest.mySavedData = self.myModel.mySavedData;
    }
}
```

I know that I could just set the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` here in the `prepareForSegue` method; however, this seems like something the popover class should deal with.

Comment: Added a solution below which provides a generic way to size a popover to any tableView size.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

set `contentSizeForViewInPopover` in `ViewDidLoad` method in `HomeViewController`

Comment: -contentSizeForViewInPopover: is deprecated in iOS 7. Use -setPopoverContentSize:animated: instead.

Comment: I believe the replacement for the call is setPreferredContentSize:

Answer (score 58):

As of iOS7 `contentSizeForViewInPopover` is deprecated. You should use `UIViewController`'s `preferredContentSize` property instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you have a popover presenting a UINavigationController. My second view controller is resetting this value but it won't adjust. It only takes the root view controller's value for some reason.

Comment: This value can also be set in IB: **ViewController's attributes inspector** `>>` Content Size `>>` **Used Preferred Explicit Size**

Answer (score 7):

`contentSizeForViewInPopover` is deprecated in iOS 7 
 
The property: `popoverContentSize` of UIPopoverController represents the size of the content view that is managed by the view controller in the contentViewController property of UIPopoverController.  
 
  [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/popoverContentSize)

The advantage is that it is available in iOS 3.2 and later, so you don't need to check device version everytime, just replace `contentSizeForViewInPopover` method with your UIPopOverController object instance.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
setPopoverContentSize:<#(CGSize)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>
```

in your segue logic block.  Useful if you want the popover size to be variable based upon   a data set, or view placement or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

```
// self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0); //Deprecated in ios7


self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0); //used instead
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
- (IBAction)setData:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *popoverContent=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UITableView *tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 680, 0, 0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

     UIView *popoverView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];

     popoverView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    popoverContent.view=popoverView;
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(200, 420);//setting the size
    popoverContent.view=tableView;
    tableView.delegate=self;
    tableView.dataSource=self;

    self.popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(400, 675, 0, 0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A little known trick to sizing your `UIPopoverViewController` to match the height of your `UITableView` is to use the tableView's `rectForSection` method to give you the height. Use the height in your viewController's `contentSizeForViewInPopover` like this:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover {
    // Currently no way to obtain the width dynamically before viewWillAppear.
    CGFloat width = 200.0; 
    CGRect rect = [self.tableView rectForSection:[self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1];
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);
    return (CGSize){width, height};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do it programmatically, but in the storyboard, before you hook up a view controller to a segue, under the attributes inspector there is a "popover, use explicit size option."  Maybe you can set the size that would work the best for your App first and not worry about the size with using code.  Hope this helps, let us know how it goes.

Comment: The problem is that my model will be a different size each time the app is run, thus I can't pinpoint an explicit size

Comment: @Nosrettap,  Yeah that wouldn't work at all if it changes.  Well, thought I would at least try.  Keep us posted to what you do, I would love to find out.